# iOS 7 - Navigation Controller Toolbar issue with setToolbarHidden: animation

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

In my Tabbed application, the main view is an UITableView, which includes a hidden searchBar (until you scroll down and it shows up, just like the Mail app).

In the navigation bar, there's a button which brings up the navigationController's toolbar with an animation.

The toolbar is positioned just above the tabBar.

The problems are:

- The animation is not smooth, there's a sort of black-ish background before the toolbar actually shows up
- When hiding the navigationBar's toolbar, the animation brings down the searchBar as well, and it shouldn't. It's like the whole view gets slided down.

The code I'm using is

```
-(void)showToolbar{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setAlpha:1.0];
    }completion:nil];
}


-(void)hideToolbar{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
                         [self.navigationController.toolbar setAlpha:0.0];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Here's a gif of what i'm getting (blurred for privacy reasons)

[image]

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: i think , the black slash is the background color of you controller ? tell me where you have added the toolbar

Comment: No I don't think so, I had the same code in another app and it was smooth. I guess that's something related to the translucency or something, I don't get it. I don't add the toolbar anywhere, it's the one built in the navigationController.

Comment: I'm using the same code to show/hide the toolbar and I'm having no issues. My guess is there's other code effecting this..

Comment: Might it be the style of the navigationBar - tabbar to affect this? I've a custom background color in both, but I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of the  black-ish background before the toolbar actually shows up is it shows your application window background color. if you do this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

Then it shows yellowish background before toolbar is coming.It will show whatever color you set in your app mainwindow it display.
It shows because in your showtoolbar is running for 0.3 sec in this time your toolbar alpha change from 0.0 to 1.0 so for some miliseconds it will be blank.

So the solution is you can change the duration time to 0.1 or you can set the same backgroundcolor to your uiwindow.. :)

Comment: Dude thanks a lot! That's a clean workaround and solved the first step, but do you have any idea why the whole view gets slided down when hiding it?

Comment: this is for [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES]

Comment: Hm so if I just use setToolbarHidden do I get the same effect? That's weird because in another app it just slides away properly without sliding the whole view.

Comment: what you want same animation what in the image or fade animation?

Comment: No I mean, I would like the toolbar to slide up when showing and slide down when hiding, all this without effecting the whole view (so without revealing the searchBar)

Comment: this is the feature of uinavigation controller you can do one thing. you have to manage auto resizing

Comment: I ended up using the nib of the tableView and embed it in a navigationController, and it worked smoothly. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, though!

Comment: i did not get the bounty